# MirrorMaker2 compatibility with Kafka 2.0.0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

Trying to understand compatibility of MM2 libraries packaged as part of core kafka release 2.4 with Kafka Cluster running with Kafka core version 2.0.0.

The major improvements to MM2 got implemented as part of the [KIP-382](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-382%3A+MirrorMaker+2.0) got merged via this [PR](https://github.com/apache/kafka/pull/6295/files).
In this PR I don’t see any changes being made to core kafka. The changes are only seen with Kafka-connect and mirrormaker related code.

As I know Kafka Connect is a client application to kafka (Similar to any standard consumer and producer application). And MM2 built on top of Kafka Connect Architecture.

Though MirrorMaker2 related libraries are bundled with Core kafka libraries i.e., 2.4 Kafka version as part of release cycles and packages, I think MM2 doesn't have absolute dependency on the same version of the Kafka Broker (i.e., the one built with kafka 2.4.).

The reason being MM2 component is client side component.

This is valid to assume that we can set MM2 using kafka core 2.4 release packages to work with Kafka Broker set up with Kafka 2.0.0?

Any responses, comments or any materials in this regard are highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Try it. Do you get any errors?

Comment: Not getting any errors and it's working. But wanted to get understanding on compatibility of MM2 setup using kafka 2.4 release against kafka cluster 2.0.0.

Comment: Just like newer clients can be used with older brokers, you can also use any Connector, including MM2